# Probability of guessing random 128-bit AES key

Tags: aes, symmetric, key-size

Consider the following five events:

1. Correctly guessing a random 128-bit AES key on the first try
2. Winning a lottery with 1 million contestants
3. Winning a lottery with 1 million contestants 5 times in a row.
4. Winning a lottery with 1 million contestants 6 times in a row
5. Winning a lottery with 1 million contestants 7 times in a row

What is the order of these events from most likely to least likely?

Comment: Possible outcomes (do not know correct english term), least likely to most likely: (5) $=(10^6)^7 = 10^{42}$, (1)$=2^{128} \approx 10^{38}$, (4)$=(10^6)^6 = 10^{36}$, (3), (2)

Comment: thanks. but would you solve it for (2) & (3)?

Comment: @farnaz: Hint for solving this basic and excellent exercise: Express odds of events 1..5 as a power of two. For events 2..5, use that a million is a thousand thousands, and a thousand is $10^3=1000$, which is only few percents from $1024=2^{10}$. You should be able to find the answer without even pencil and paper, much less a calculator.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: using powers of two, the problem (reduced to 1,4,and 5) boils down to ordering 128, 6⋅20, and 7⋅20. Using powers of 10, we'd be ordering 128⋅3/10, 6⋅6, and 7⋅6. I find the first method easier to perform mentally.

Comment: @fgrieu You've got a point. I don't think either method strains our brains to capacity though :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about counting, with only a superficial application to cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To randomly guess a single key from a 128-bit key space has a chance of 1 divided by the number of elements or $\frac{1} {2^{128}}$ where $2^{128}$ is the number of keys possible.

To get ballpark figures to convert between base 2 exponents and base 10 exponents you can use the following trick:

**Because $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 10^3$ you can easily count the number of decimal digits, then divide by 3 and multiply with 10. To go from the number of bits to the number of decimal digits multiply by 3 and divide by 10.**

If you want to be more precise: you can divide or multiply with the constant value $\log_2(10) = \frac1{\log_{10}(2)} = \ln(10) / \ln(2) = 3.321928094\ldots$

(easy to remember in your pocket calculator or phone).

So as an AES key is 128 bits you can easily see that it represents about $10^{\frac {128 * 3}  {10}} = 10^{38.4}$ possible values. The bigger the possible value the less likely it is to guess (or brute force) one.

---

To get to the possibility of winning the lottery you have to calculate $\frac1n$ where $n$ is the number of contestants. To calculate the chance of winning it x times in a row you have to calculate $(\frac1n)^{x}$ which is equal to $\frac1{n^x}$.

As you can see that one million is $10^6$ you can then see that winning it 5 times in a row would be identical to pick one value out of $10^{6^5} = 10^{30}$ values. So you have a significantly better chance of winning the lottery 5 times: $\frac1{10^{30}}$ than picking a random 128 bit AES key: $\approx \frac1{10^{38.4}}$