# Can someone randomly guess the key to AES 256 bit encryption?

Tags: aes, keys, attack

Is it possible that someone can randomly input a key to AES 256 bit encryption and it is correct? What are the chances of this happening? Is it even possible or not?

Comment: That'd make them the luckiest person in the multiverse.

Comment: Yes, but its possible.  That's  statistics.

Answer (score 10):

There are $2^{256}$ different AES keys, the chance that you hit the one right one on first try is thus $2^{-256}=\frac1{2^{256}}$.

To put this into perspective, here's a list of events that is roughly a billion times more likely to *all* happen (copied from [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin)'s [answer on Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2947/71460)):

> - The computer spontaneously catches fire during the key generation process.
> - Great Britain is wiped out by a falling asteroid during the very same second.
> - A rogue gorilla escaped from a zoo enters your living room and mauls you.
> - You win millions of dollars at the lottery three times in a row.

According to his answer, these events have roughly the chances of happening $2^{-45},2^{-50},2^{-60},2^{-71}$ each, which multiplies to $2^{-226}$ if you want all four to happen which is still roughly a billion times more likely than finding a 256-bit key on first try.

Note that this assumes that the key does indeed contain 256-bit of entropy, ie it can indeed take all the $2^{256}$ different values.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, this is possible... **but**, you have a better chance being hit by a meteor within the next second than seeing that happen as it practically boils down to "getting *extremely* lucky" with a brute-force attack.

Think about it: [**256 bits** (32 octets)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/256-bit). You can do the math yourself to calculate the chances in both a *best case* as well as a *worst case* scenario.

Skipping the details the other answers already provided, you're thinking about someone lucky enough to "guess" that one correct password out of a pool of 1.1579209e+77 possibilities. To put that in perspective… this means that, **on average**, an attacker would need around and about <sub>$$57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968$$</sub> attempts to guess the correct password (better: key).

That is, assuming an optimal case with both a correct and safe AES implementation as well as cryptographically secure creation and handling of key material. Also, this doesn't look at other potential attack vectors like exploiting a weak block-cipher mode of operation or the likes - as the question specifically asks about the chance of a "randomly input a key" being correct.

---

Also see the related question [*"Probability of guessing random 128-bit AES key"*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/probability-of-guessing-random-128-bit-aes-key?rq=1) as well as it's accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For AES-256 in order for someone to guess a key they would need to guess the sequence of 256 bits. There are $2^{256}$ possible sequences of length 256 bits and only one of them can be the correct key. For comparison the estimated number of atoms in the visible universe is $2^{265}$.

The possibility of randomly guessing 256-bit long sequence is $\frac{1}{2^{256}} = 2^{-256}$.

So while this is theoretically possible, the possibility of actual guessing is incredibly low.